# Laravel posting and comments , i cannot comment after i created a new post using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

when i refresh the page using the browser everything is working fine i could still comment and i could also add new post but the problem is when i create a new post(which means a post like a facebook post) i cannot comment anymore on any post. here is my Homeview :

```html
<div class="All-Post-Display" id="PostRefresh">
  <div class="container">
  @foreach($latest as $late)
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
     <div class="outside-pannel">
      <div class="person">
       <img src="/styleimage/facebook.jpg">
       <h2>{{$late->user->name}} {{$late->user->lastname}}</h2><br>
       <h4>{{$late->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="body-of-post">
       <p>{{$late->body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="like-comment-share">
       <form>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Like</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>Comment</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share"></i>Share</a></li>
        </ul>
       </form>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-section" >
       <div class="total-likes">
         <a href=""><h3>3 likes your post</h3></a>
       </div>
       <div class="comment-form">
       @foreach($late->comments as $comment)
        <div class="display-comments">
         <div class="comment-img">
          <img src="/styleimage/facebook.jpg">
         </div>
         <div class="comment-container">
          <div class="comment-content">
           <a name="postername" href="#">rd</a> <span></span>
           <div class="reply-like">
            <ul>
             <li><a href="">Like</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Reply</a></li>
             <li><h6>just now</h6></li>
            </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       @endforeach
        <div>
         <div class="commenting-container">
         <img src="/styleimage/facebook.jpg">
         <textarea rows="1" id="comment-body{{$late->id}}" name="body" placeholder="Write a comment..."></textarea>
         <input type="text" name="commentable" id="posting-id{{$late->id}}" value="{{$late->id}}" style="display: none;">
          <div class="emojis">
           <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i></a></li>
           </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
          
         
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#comment-body{{$late->id}}').keypress(function (e) {
         if (e.which == 13) {
             var comment = $('#comment-body{{$late->id}}').val();
             var postCommentedId = $('#posting-id{{$late->id}}').val();
             $.ajax({
               url: '/comment',
               type: 'post',
               data: {'commentable_id':postCommentedId,'body':comment,'_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()},
               success: function (data) {
                console.log('success');
                $('#comment-body{{$late->id}}').val(null);

               },
               error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('errorThrown');
                 }
             });
         }
           
        });
    });
   </script>
  @endforeach
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
{{csrf_field()}}
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#ButtonPost').click(function (event) {
      var thebody = $('#bodyPost').val();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'index',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'body':thebody,'_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()},
        success: function (data) {
         $('#PostRefresh').load(location.href + ' #PostRefresh');
         $('#bodyPost').val(null);
        }
       });
     });
  });


</script>
```

after running this AJAX at the bottom the AJAX inside my @foreach doesn't work , id="PostRefresh" is gonna be refreshed when i make new post. im also using id="{{id of post}}" to make them unique in every post, Please Help Thank you...

Comment: note: my comment is still not done but i could save it to database so i know if it worked or not

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking; what exactly is the connection to `facebook` here?

Comment: i was currently copying facebook posting  using laravel . where i can login make a post and give the post a comment , my problem is whenever i make a post  it makes the comment non functional , what i can do right now is i  need to reload the whole page in order to comment again

Comment: What, are you using actual content from Facebook, via their API? Or do you just mean you want to implement something in the same way Facebook does? Then please don’t tag it `facebook`, that’s not what this tag is for.

Comment: oh i'm sorry  , newbee here  i already removed the tag, no im just copying it from scratch , its just like a todo list with a comment on every list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
$('#ButtonPost').click(function (event) ...
```

Try to use

```
$(document).on('click','#ButtonPost',(function (event) ...
```

Here the problem is, once you create new DOM then you don't have id of new element created to your jquery id not working.
But with this code you will get jquery code linked to every element of if #buttonPost.